# How can i access member functions of a class via Class pointer of pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers

Here below is my C++ code, and I'm commenting out my problem in below code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
public:
    virtual void f1(){
    cout << "f1 from base\n"; }

   virtual void f2(){
   cout << "f2 from base\n";
 }
};

class D1: public Base {
public:
 virtual void f1(){
cout << "f1 from D1\n";
}
};

class D2: public Base {
public:
 virtual void f2(){
cout << "f2 from D2\n";
}
};


int main(){
Base* b1 = new D1;
b1->f1();
b1->f2();

delete b1;

Base* b2 = new D2;
b2->f1();
b2->f2();

Base** ptr = &b2;
// here how to use member function
// of b2


return 0;
}
```

I want to access `f1()`,function of `D1` class by `ptr` pointer.
I've declared `Base**` and assigned `b2` to it. Where `b2` is pointer of `Base*` class.

Comment: By dereferencing both pointers in one way or the other.

Comment: This is a basic syntax question better answered by reading a good book or tutorial than asking on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to deference the `Base**` once so you can call the function by pointer base class.

One possible way is to write

```
(*ptr)->f1();
```

Comment: I have compiled my code with this syntax (**ptr).f1(); and it is working, Is this valid?

Comment: Yes, because you are dereferencing the pointer twice. In the interest of readable code, I prefer my version, but the difference is mostly stylistic.